# How to implement Sql Server 2016 mobile publisher on existing Report Server

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2014

Currently working on sql server 2014 (SSRS 2014) on window server 2012 R2.

Requirement is to publish Sql Server mobile publisher report on report manager on SSRS 2014.

I installed Sql Server 2016 mobile publisher and developed some report but how to publish it on ssrs 2014 (Is it possible ?).

My problem is how to implement and use Sql Server 2016 mobile report on my current scenario.
Is this possible ? or upgrade to sql server 2016.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Mobile Reports (nee Datazen) is only available on SSRS 2016.